# How to find punctuation marks in str python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, punctuation

its a kattis problem "Canadians, eh?"
if the sentence ends with "eh?" the person is canadian and if not its an imposter
this is my code rn

```
a = input()
found = a.find('e')
found2= a[found + 1]
found3=a[found2 + 1]

if a[found + 1] == 'h' and found3 =='?':
    print("Canadian!")
else : 
    print("Imposter!")
```

i have no problem with finding "eh" but the it cant find'?' mark
giving me an 'can only concatenate str (not "int") to str' error
i hope you understood my problem
this is the kattis problem link if you wanna check it out
https://open.kattis.com/problems/canadianseh

Comment: Why are you searching for `e`, `h` and `?` separately? I suggest investigating `endswith()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this :

```
a = input()
print("Canadian!" if a.endswith("eh?") else "Imposter!")
```

Use [str.endswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to check if a string ends with any particular sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if a[-3:]=='eh?':
 return 'Canadian!'
else:
 return 'Imposter!'
```

Comment: @AnkitSharma it does provide the answer. 'If' condition is checking the last three characters and vice versa